# Why do some files in Mac OS X say 'Date Modified' as '24 January 1984 08:00'?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

When I am copying files on a Macintosh, I notice that the folder says that its Modified/Created timestamp is 24 January 1984 08:00. Why is this particular timestamp is used? Is it something to do with when Mac OS X was first released?

Comment: Although the article is referencing Mountain Lion nonetheless it's still applicable, have a look at: [Mountain Lion easter egg references debut of original Apple Macintosh](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/26/mountain_lion_easter_egg_references_debut_of_original_apple_macintosh)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is the Mac's birthday.

Jan. 24, 1984, was the date Jobs took to the stage to show off the very first Macintosh in a live demonstration. The presentation from Jobs stirred an audience of more than 3,000 people into a frenzy when the computer read aloud, "Hello, I'm Macintosh. It sure is great to get out of that bag."

http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/26/mountain_lion_easter_egg_references_debut_of_original_apple_macintosh

Answer (score 3):

January 24, 1984 is the date that the first Macintosh [went on sale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_128K).

Apple do love their [easter eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(interaction_design))...